# Show that $D^m=S^{-1}\cdot M^m \cdot S$

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, induction

I have to show, that $D^m=S^{-1}\cdot M^m \cdot S$ for all $m \geq 1$, given that M is diagonalizable with diagonal matrix $D=S^{-1}\cdot M \cdot S$. (As side question: is it true if I say that D is a Jordan form of M?)

It is pretty obvious that proof goes by induction. We even got the basic step done. This is true for $m=1$. Now supposed, that this is true for any $m \ in \mathbb{N}$, then the statement also holds for $m + 1$.

This is where I'm left in the darkness: I can either start multiplying the whole matrix equation with D or M to get: $D^{m+1}=D^m\cdot D =S^{-1}\cdot M^m \cdot S \cdot D = D\cdot D^m = D \cdot S^{-1}\cdot M^m \cdot S$ (and similarly for M). I get the following relations: $D^m D = D^m M$ and $M^m\cdot D = M^m M$, but have no idea how to use this in order to obtain $D^{m+1}= S^{-1}\cdot M^{m+1} \cdot S$, what we need to show.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$$D^{m+1}=D^{m}.D=(S^{-1}.M^m.S).(S^{-1}.M.S)$$

Now use the fact that $S.S^{-1}=I$ and $M^m.M=M^{m+1}$ to get $D^{m+1}=S^{-1}.M^{m+1}.S$.

Answer (score 1):

HINT :

Maybe you forgot to use $D=S^{-1}\cdot M\cdot S$ as

$$D^{m+1}=D^m\cdot D =(S^{-1}\cdot M^m \cdot S) \cdot (S^{-1}\cdot M\cdot S)  $$